# How to improve antlr4 runtime performance on c++ target?

Tags: c++, performance, antlr4

My tool intention is calculate the results parsed from antlr4. The inputs had break into many lines, 
eg: 1+1,
    3*4,
    ...
Each line will init the parser and call the visitor. Therefore, if there is 1000 lines, it will call 1000 times of antlr4 parser. It run perfectly except the performances are slightly slow on the device. I hope to improve the performances even there is 1second faster.

I'm using antlr4.7 as runtime. The runtime target is on c++.

```
for (itFormulas = fMap - > begin(); itFormulas != fMap - > end(); itFormulas++) 
{
  auto initStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  ANTLRInputStream input(itFormulas - > second);
  FormulaLexer lexer( & input);
  CommonTokenStream tokens( & lexer);
  FormulaParser parser( & tokens);
  FormulaParser::MainContext * mainContext = parser.main();

  auto initEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration < double > totalInit = initEnd - initStart;

  //calculate time
  totalInitTime += totalInit.count();

  auto visitStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  EvaluatorVisitor visitor(formulaMap, resultMap, inputMaps);

  try {
    antlrcpp::Any result = visitor.visit(mainContext - > children[0]);

    auto visitEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration < double > totalElapsed = visitEnd - visitStart;

    //calculate time
    totalVisitTime += totalElapsed.count();

    resultMap - > insert(pair < string, double > (itFormulas - > first, v));
  } catch (EvaluationException ex) {
    string from = "Mistake" + string(" itFormulas->") + itFormulas - > first;
  }
}
```

If the total routine will took 5seconds
The parser time will be around 1 second, and the visitor time will be 4seconds.

I expect the time could be shorter, and wish to know which part can be optimised.

Comment: This is an impossible task for us, because we don't know any of the functions you are calling. Compile your code with optimization on (-O3) and use a performance measuring tool such as `perf` or `Intel vTune`. and figure out why this is your hotspot.

Comment: Right, I'd split the various parts in your processing (eg. lexing, parsing, tree walking) and see which one takes most of the time. Also the structure of your grammar is important (e.g. use of predicates).

Comment: Parse times for Antlr depend on the grammar. You could use the fastest runtime--generally accepted as Cpp--and a crappy grammar, and still end up with terrible performance. We don't know your grammar; it's the most important fact we need to know. After one writes a grammar that parses correctly, one then must "optimize" the grammar to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime update 4.9.3 should improve the performance thanks to https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/3318